# Uniqueness constraint and indexing issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I must be doing something incorrectly, or have a misconceptions about constraints and indexing.  I have the following:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:User) ASSERT u.user_id IS UNIQUE
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(user_id)
```

I've tried alternating the order, but regardless, I'm getting:

```
Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintAlreadyExists
```

or

```
Neo.ClientError.Schema.IndexAlreadyExists
```

depending on the ordering.

I don't understand why I wouldn't be able to do this.  I want look-ups to be fast for a `user_id`, which is why I'm indexing, and I also want to make sure that `user_id` is unique, which is why I have a constraint.

What am I misunderstanding?  How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding the unique constraint will also add the index on that property- so the unique constraint is sufficient.

See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-constraints.html

> "Note that adding a uniqueness constraint on a property will also add
>   an index on that property, so you cannot add such an index separately.
>   Cypher will use that index for lookups just like other indexes. If you
>   drop a constraint and still want an index on the property, you will
>   have to create the index."

Comment: Completely missed that.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As Luanne said, adding a uniqueness constraint on a property will also create an index on it.

**To make `user_id` unique and indexed, you should use this:**

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (user:User) ASSERT user.user_id IS UNIQUE

>>> Added 1 constraint, returned 0 rows in 107 ms
```

**To verify that the index has been added correctly:**

```
:SCHEMA

>>> Indexes
>>>   ON :User(user_id)             ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
>>> 
>>> Constraints
>>>   ON (user:User) ASSERT user.user_id IS UNIQUE
```

**Note, if you try to remove the index that has been automatically created by the uniqueness constraint, it will fail:**

```
DROP INDEX ON :User(user_id)

>>> Unable to drop index on :User(user_id): Index belongs to constraint: :User(user_id)
```

**The correct way to remove it is to remove the uniqueness contraint:**

```
DROP CONSTRAINT ON (user:User) ASSERT user.user_id IS UNIQUE

>>> Removed 1 constraint, returned 0 rows in 108 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a constraint will automatically create an index on that property. You have to create an index manually if you create an index only.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-schema-index.html

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-constraints.html